# How to programmatically install demo data on WordPress theme activation

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

Spend some time searching, without good answer... I am developing new WordPress theme and need to import demo categories from my demo data XML file on theme activation programmatically. 
Need help if you have code sample or if you know some tutorial article about this topic!

Comment: Have you checked out this in the codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test?

Comment: Tnx Dave. I know how to import data, but i need to do it automatically while theme is activated (on the fly)!